# Can't run Python code in Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-prompt

I'm new to Python and I created my first piece of code which is simply

```
print('Hello World!')
```

and it works fine and I named it **hello.py**. When I try to open the file it says with "python **hello.py**"

I get an error message that says

> File "hello.py", line 1
>       PYthon 3.4.4 (v3.3.3:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1.600 64 bit (AMD65)] on win32
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I added Python to the PATH so I don't know what's the issue

Comment: How did you save it (with what editor)? You're on Windows and I guess that the `^M` can upset you.

Comment: Seems like you typed it all by hand (`AMD65` LOL)

Comment: Please paste the exact text from the command prompt, including the command line that you're running.

Comment: you should [learn what the command line is](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html) and how to [run `python` in it](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to put those lines into your script. They come from the interpreter, giving information *to you*. You're only supposed to include in your script the commands that *you* want to give *to the interpreter*. In your case, your `hello.py` file should consist entirely of this:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

and nothing else.